# I can't understand this issue java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I've strange issue, that My application is working fine on some devices, But its crashing one of the client device(on Galaxy Nexus 4.1.1 v) at app starting screen. I get this stack trace from ACRA report.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1731)
        at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1704)
        at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:164)
        at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:204)
        at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:281)
        at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:284)
        at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:170)
        at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:5843)
        at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:5741)
        at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6098)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Im seeing above stack trace. I'm unable to understand the issue.

Please help me on tacking the issue.

Thank you.